# Get text content in EditText ListView after click button issue

Tags: android, listview

I have a Listview of EditText and I need to get the String values of each edited row when I click a confirm button, but I don't know how.

I have tried to adapt some sample with no success ( **I get always the default values and not the edited values**).

My attempt is this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    static int nItems;

    ImageButton confirmButton;
    ListView myList;

    ListViewAdapterEditText adapterG1, adapterG2, adapterG3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .....
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaG1);
        myList.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        adapterG1 = new ListViewAdapterEditText();
        myList.setAdapter(adapterG1);

    }

    OnClickListener mConfirmButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ArrayList a1 = adapterG1.getItems();
                for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
                    System.out.println(a1.get(i)
                            + "\n\n");
        }
    };

    public class ListViewAdapterEditText extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        public ArrayList myItems = new ArrayList();
        ListItem listItem;

        public ListViewAdapterEditText() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
                listItem = new ListItem();
                listItem.caption = "Caption" + i;
                myItems.add(listItem);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return myItems.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getItems() {
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++) {
                ListItem li = (ListItem) myItems.get(i);
                items.add(li.getCaption());
            }
            return items;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_row,
                        null);
                holder.caption = (EditText) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ItemCaption);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            // Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
            holder.caption.setText(((ListItem) myItems.get(position)).caption);
            // holder.caption.setText(myItems.get(position).caption);
            holder.caption.setId(position);

            // we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
            holder.caption
                    .setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                            if (!hasFocus) {
                                final int position = v.getId();
                                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                                ((ListItem) myItems.get(position)).caption = Caption
                                        .getText().toString();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            EditText caption;
        }

        class ListItem {
            String caption;

            public String getCaption() {
                return caption;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your OnFocusChangeListener is called? If you edit the text in EditText then tap the confirm button, this listener will not be called in touch mode since the focus is still on the EditText.

Update: Consider the situation you edited the text in a EditText while didn't confirm and scrolled the ListView so that the item view is recycled, I'm not sure what is your preferred way, but if you want store the edited data, you can use setRecyclerListener(android.widget.AbsListView.RecyclerListener) to get notified when a item view is recycled so you can saved the edit result. To save the result of EditText showing on screen, you use methods like getChildAt to get item views visible on screen then get the EditText's text.

Update2: Another better and clean way is use TextWatcher and addTextChangeListener, this will notifies you when the text in EditText is changed.

Update3: I just write the following sample and test it, and it works on my phone. :)

Update4: I removed the previous code cause its performance is bad and creates a lot objects, you can check the following full sample instead:

Activity code :

```
package com.example.asynctasktest;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * @author Daniel Chow
 *
 * May 26, 2013 12:57:49 AM
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        final TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm_button);
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<String> items = adapter.getItems();
                for (int i = 0, n = items.size(); i < n; i++) {
                    Log.e("", items.get(i));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Adapter code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.example.asynctasktest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * @author Daniel Chow
 * 
 *         May 26, 2013 1:13:02 AM */
public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            items.add("caption " + i);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return new ArrayList<String>(items);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 12;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new EditText(context);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.editText = (EditText) convertView;
            holder.watcher = new EditTextWatcher();
            holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(holder.watcher);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.watcher.setTarget(position);
        holder.editText.setText(items.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    private class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private int target;

        public void setTarget(int target) {
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            items.set(target, s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        EditText editText;
        EditTextWatcher watcher;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe is this the cause of null values...Any suggestion to fix this problem?

Comment: I just updated the answer, I think TextWatcher will solve your problem, since you only need to save the edit result when text in EditText is changed.

Comment: Could you give me a sample? I have considered the alternative of a TextWatcher etc. but I don't know how I implement this. I need simply to get the new values of a ListView of EditText on click. I have tried many sample but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I usually follow a simpler technique

```
public class Item_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
      private String[] Val;

 public Item_Adapter () {
    Val= new String[nItems];

 }
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           ViewHolder holder;
 ///bla bla

holder.caption
                .setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (!hasFocus) {
                            final int position = v.getId();
                            final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                            ((ListItem) myItems.get(position)).caption = Caption
                                    .getText().toString();
                             Val[position]= Caption
                                    .getText().toString();

                        }
                    }
                });
      ///bla bla
    return convertView;
}
     /////most important returning your array so you can use it in the Activity
    public String[] getVal() {
    return Val;
}
```

Comment: You do know that `bla bla` actually mean your old code just Add `getVal()` code

Comment: I have tried but I get the error *Type mismatch cannot convert form ViewHolder to View* on return holder.

Comment: @AndreaF its was convertView

Comment: Fixed this error but now I get a nullpointer exception in  *convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_row,
                        null);*

Comment: Now I have fixed all compile errors but I get the same issue of my original code, in MyActivity class I get always null values when I try to print the array using getVal(), seems that won't update with the new edited values

Comment: @AndreaF should i suggest a different approach which I ususally if your haven't found the answer yet

Comment: fell free to suggest all if you think should be usefull, thanks